# How to find if a substring from a string vector is contained in another group/vector/list c++

Tags: list, c++11, vector, find, substring

let me give an example:I have three groups of strings which will have a fixed size, I thought of using lists. Let's say I name them Red, Green, Blue:

```
std::string Red[] = {"apple", "rose mary", "watermelon"};
std::string Green[] = {"cucumber", "avocado", "pine tree"};
std::string Blue[] = {"sea", "lake"};
```

I have found examples here where we search one item inside each of these lists, and they find it if the string matches, for example in that case I should have :

```
std::string myinput = "watermelon";
if (std::find(std::begin(Red), std::end(Red), myinput) != std::end(Red))
{
  cout << "found " << myinput << " in Red" <<  endl;
}
```

Ok so far, but I want something different:
I want to scan a vector with 1000 elememnts, and myinput belongs to one of those elements which I access like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Vector.size(); j++){
    if (Vector[j].message ==  contains a string from one of the groups ){
        cout<< Vector[j].message << endl;}
}
```

The Vector[j].message will be a string which has this format:

```
"flag: She adores watermelon"
"flag: They visited the lake"
"flag: He has cucumber for salad"
"flag: Wacamole made of avocado"
```

You see that the substring flag is common in all strings of the vectors. However, the watermelon doesn't exist in another group of strings.

The goal is to scan each group of lists and find that the element of the vector 
*"flag: She adores watermelon"* is listed in group *Red*. This should not be listed in the group yellow just because of the substring "flag". 
Also, I want the substring to contain the whole string stated in the group, for example if the Vector contains an element like *"flag: the plant has many pines"* , this should not be listed to the Green group, it should be uncategorized.

Then these messages should be categorized and printed in different colors, red first in red colour etc.

First, do you agree with lists' idea? Do you suggest a more efficient way? What do you suggest for the substring search?

Excuse the lame examples and if my description in the title is not clear. I am new to this and looking for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.  Instead of this:

```
{"apple", "rose mary", "watermelon"}
```

Use this:

```
std::regex red("apple|rose mary|watermelon");
```

Then for each input line:

```
if (std::regex_search(line, red)) {
    // it's red
}
```

You can then create a `vector<pair<regex, string>>` and name each pattern:

```
vector<pair<regex, string>> patterns = {
    {"apple|rose mary|watermelon", "red"},
    {"cucumber|avocado|pine tree", "green"},
    {"sea|lake", "blue"},
};
```

This way you can easily iterate over all the patterns and get the color for any match.